# What would the usable IP addresses be for a /28?

Tags: networking

New to networking and have been asked to setup a server. The colocation provider gave the following IP addresses:

```
Address block: xxx.xxx.xxx.225/28
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.240
```

The datacenter would only be putting in 1 network cable into the server.

Comment: Lookup "online ip subnet calculators", or any of the dozens of "ip subnet calculator" or "CIDR calculator" apps available for most popular smartphone OS'es

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

Answer (score 2):

Subnet address size of 28 leaves 4 bits for hosts. 2^4 minus two not usable addresses is 14. Usually, one of those is used for the ISP default gateway.

However, ...225/28 doesn't work since the host end bits are not 0000 but 0001. Possibly, this is the default gateway in the ...224/28 network.